# Slim PUT returns NULL

Tags: php, jquery, http, put, slim

I have a problem with the Slim Framework and a PUT request. I have a litte jQuery script that that will update an expiry time when a button is clicked.

```
$("#expiry-button").click(function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();

     $.ajax({
         url: 'http://www.domain.com/expiry/38/', 
         dataType: 'json',
         type: 'PUT',
         contentType: 'application/json',
         data: {aid:'38'},
         success: function(){
             var text = "Time updated";
             $('#expiry').text(text).addClass("ok");
          },
          error: function(data) { 
             var text = "Something went wrong!";
             $('#expiry').text(text).addClass("error");
           }
     });
});
```

I always get "Something went wrong!"

In my index.php where I have configured Slim, I have this

```
$app->put('/expiry/:aid/', function($aid) use($app, $adverts) {
    $id = $app->request()->put($aid);
    $adverts->expand_ad_time($id["aid"]);
});
```

if I `var_dump($id)` I get NULL

the Response Header looks like this:

```
Status Code: 200
Pragma: no-cache
Date: Wed, 08 May 2013 12:04:16 GMT
Content-Encoding: gzip
Server: Apache/2.2.16 (Debian)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.3-7+squeeze15
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: Keep-Alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=100
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
```

and the Request Body

```
Request Url: http://www.domain.com/expiry/38/
Request Method: PUT
Status Code: 200
Params: {
    "aid": "38"
}
```

So the communication is there, but not the desired result. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you should check that json data, because it isn't valid: http://jsonlint.com/
Try with this: {"aid":"38"}

If you need that JSON data than i would do something like this:

```
$app->put('/expiry/:aid/', function($aid) use($app, $adverts) {
    // Decode the request data
    $test = json_decode($app->getInstance()->request()->getBody());
    echo $test->aid; // from the JSON DATA
});
```

If you want the number from the url /expiry/**38**/ then, you can get it from the variable $aid, which you've passed to the function

```
$app->put('/expiry/:aid/', function($aid) use($app, $adverts) {
    echo $aid; // from the url
});
```

I hope this may help you