# Cannot get body from PUT request with Slim Framework

Tags: rest, slim, http-put

I am trying to retrieve parameters from a PUT request using the Slim framework. When parsing parameters form a POST body, I can simply use `$request->post('param')` to retrieve the value in param. However, when I use `$request->put('param')`, I always receive null.

My PUT body is formed like this: `param=value&otherparam=othervalue&foo=bar`...

P.S.: I have already looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16440344/slim-put-returns-null), but the answer did not use the `put()`-Method.

Comment: Please add your PUT route and explain how you're making your PUT request. If it's via a form, please share the form.

Comment: My route is /api/post/:id (e.g. /post/id/2). I'm sending the request via Fiddler currently and later through an android app

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're getting `null` back from `$request->put('param')` because you're trying to call that on a `POST` route.  You'll need to create a separate `PUT` route (or use `map` and `via`) before you can get the `PUT` param.

Additionally, I don't recommend adding the HTTP verb to the route.  That leads to some really confusing architecture.

Adding an additional route:

```
$app->post('/api/something/:id', function () {});
$app->put('/api/something/:id', function () {});
```

Using [Custom HTTP methods](http://docs.slimframework.com/#Custom-HTTP-Methods) (`map` and `via`)

```
$app->map('/api/something/:id', function () {})->via('POST', 'PUT');
```

Please see the [`PUT` routing documentation](http://docs.slimframework.com/#PUT-Routes), and pay special attention to the Method Override section.

**UPDATE**: Working Example

Here is an example PUT request I whipped up:

```
$app->put('/test/:id', function ($id) use ($app) {
    $name = $app->request->put('name');
    echo sprintf('PUT request for resource id %d, name "%s"', (int) $id, $name);
});
```

I'm calling it with cURL from the command line like so:

```
curl -X PUT -d name=arthur http://slim-tutorial.dev/test/2
```

The result:

```
PUT request for resource id 2, name "arthur"%
```

If you've got a working Slim application and the above doesn't work for you, likely the problem is somewhere outside of Slim, perhaps in how you're testing or a typo in your route or test parameters.

Comment: The 'post' in the route is coincidential with the HTTP verb. It's actually a 'post' in a message board

Comment: Actually, I am calling the correct route with PUT and I have verified my code up to that point. `$request->is_Put()` returned true, so my sole problem is getting the parameter out of the body

Comment: Ah, a post in a message board. Got it!  So you're getting PUT but not getting any params.  See my updated example above, and try testing with curl like I did.

Comment: Awesome, that worked. Must be a bug in Fiddler then, since curl works fine